# Closed form for $ \frac{H_k}{k^2} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to solve some problem and came across the following series:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}
$$

I tried to find a closed form for that series but could not. Also I looked some articles related to harmonic sum but it did not help me too.

Any hints and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the exact results or asymptotics?

Comment: You can use the fact that $H_k=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\,dx$.

Comment: I want exact results(if they exist of course). @Tolaso I tried to use that identity, but after substituting it in the series could not go further.

Comment: It is equal to $-1+2\zeta(3)$. Where $\zeta(3)$ is [transcendental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant).

Comment: Did you swip integration and summation?

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathcal{H}_k}{k^2} &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\,dx \\ 
 &=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-x^k}{k^2}\,dx\\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{x^k}{k^2} \right )\,dx\\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\left ( \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^2} \right )\,dx\\ 
\end{aligned}$$

which is quite easy from now on.. Of course if you compute this, then your original series will fall easily. You just go one term ahead. Of course you have to be careful

Comment: I just gave a solution. I don't know if it suits you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the suggestion I gave above:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathcal{H}_k}{k^2} &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\,dx \\ 
 &=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-x^k}{k^2}\,dx\\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{x^k}{k^2} \right )\,dx\\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\left ( \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^2} \right )\,dx\\ 
 &=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-{\rm Li_2}(x)}{1-x}\,dx \\
 &=\ln(1-x)\left ( \frac{\pi^2}{6}-{\rm Li_2}(x) \right )\bigg|_0^1 + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2 (1-x)}{x}\,dx \\
 &=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\,dx \\
 &=2\zeta(3)
\end{aligned}$$

hence the original series evaluates to $2\zeta(3)-1$. 
The last integral is evaluated using the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: @user12127 Of course for the last integral you can apply parts and then use the equation ${\rm Li_2}$ satisfies and reduce it that way.

It is just a matter of preference. Both lead down to the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotic result is really easy: just notice $H_k \sim \log k$, so the resulting sum is a monotone decreasing function, hence it's asymptotically bounded by the corresponding integral: $\int_{1}^n \frac{\log x dx}{x^2}$ which is easily solved by IBP and the result is $O(\frac{\log n }{n^3})$.